# How to make plain text files application specific in Spring cloud config server?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I am working with microservices and using Spring cloud config server to store configurations centrally in a GIT repo. I have some application specific xml files which I am able to get the xml file from config server by using the following URL:
**{Spring-cloud-server-uri}/{name}/{profile}/{label}/{path}**

I am able to segregate files based upon profiles such as development, test etc., But is there any way to mention application name while saving a xml file to make it application specific.

Lets assume for yml or properties file we save them something like this :

{application-name}-{profile-name}.properties

But according to spring cloud documentation it gives us option only for storing it according to profile:

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__serving_plain_text.html

But what I want is something like this:
log-{application-name}-{profile-name}.xml

because withour this I dont know what is the significance of 'application' in 
**{Spring-cloud-server-uri}/{applicationname}/{profile}/{label}/{path}**

Thanks in advance, let me know if I am thinking in some direction that is not a supported feature of spring cloud config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised a same issue in the spring-cloud-config GitHub repository and I believe it is not possible as of now.

[See the issue here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1159).